# List index out of range mistake, pop() method (Python)

Tags: python

The following code if executed results in a mistake: List index out of range.

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        for i in range(1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                nums.pop(i)
        return len(nums)
```

As I thought at first, this mistake arises because you can`t remove elements from a list that you are iterating through. But this seems not to be the case. If you use the same code, but also use `reversed()` method as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(nums))):
            if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                nums.pop(i)
        return len(nums)
```

No mistake arises, yet still this code removes elements from a list while iterating through it.

So what actually causes the mistake in the first case? Or maybe `reversed()` method creates a new iterator on every turn of the cycle and that is why no mistake arises in the second case?

Comment: You can use `nums = list(set(nums))` to remove duplicates and keep it as a list.

Comment: What is the problem try to solve?  You should make it clear by adding the detail *descriptions* first.

Comment: It's causing the *error* because you've changed the *index* while looping/and remove the items at the same time.  - Try this input - ```[1, 1, 2]```    But while you're working from the backward, the index is not being *affected* so it's working!

Comment: question was asked not to find a solution to the problem, but to understand why in this particular case the mistake arises and why it does not arise if using ```reversed()```

Comment: It's explained in the previous comment already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop works on index. And it updates list and make it shorter for next iteration. After few iterations list is small enough that it cant find larger index.

Whereas in second case you are always removing last element from list and in next iteration you are getting smaller number as index, so it works.

Iteration 1-
Method 1- 023456789
Method 2- 012345678

Iteration 2-
Method 1- 02456789
Method 2- 01234567

Iteration 3-
Method 1- 0246789
Method 2- 0123456

Iteration 4-
Method 1- 024689
Method 2- 012345

Iteration 5-
Method 1- 02468
Method 2- 01234

Iteration 6-
Method 1- 024689
Method 2- 0123

Here it gives error.

As index 6 is not there.